# Access children's properties of a component in Angular 2

Tags: angular, ionic2, viewchild

I'm working with **Angular 2** and **Ionic 2** and I would like to get a property from a parent component.

So my parent composent is a class named "*ServicesPage*", and my child component is named "*AddonCell*".

**ServicesPage.html**

```
<ion-content>
  <ul *ngIf='savedAddons'>
    <addon-cell [type]="addon" *ngFor="let addon of savedAddons"></addon-cell>
  </ul>
</ion-content>
```

**ServicesPage.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'page-services',
  templateUrl: 'services.html'
})

export class ServicesPage {
    // [...]
    refreshInstalledAddons() : void {
        console.log("[+] Getting properties of all addon-cell ...");
        // I would like a for loop here to get all AddonCell objects
        // and access properties like : myAddon.myVar
    }
}
```

**AddonCell.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'addon-cell',
  template: `<div #target></div>`
})
export class AddonCell {
  @ViewChild('target', {read: ViewContainerRef}) target;
  @Input() type;
  myVar = false; // <---- Trying to get this variable
  //[...]
}
```

**UPDATE**

**AddonModule**

```
// Angular core component
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AddonCell } from './components/system/common/cell.component';

// Importing and exporting all addons
export { MeteoAddon }       from './components/meteo/meteo.addon';
import { MeteoAddon }       from './components/meteo/meteo.addon';

import { MeteoPagesModule } from './components/meteo/pages/meteo.module';

// Creating an array containg addons class names
// Please note, it's used for further instanciations
export let classNameArray = ["MeteoAddon"];

export let addonsMap = {
  'MeteoAddon' : MeteoAddon };

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AddonCell,
    MeteoAddon],
  imports: [ MeteoPagesModule ], // Importing all addon's pages
  entryComponents: [ MeteoAddon ],
  exports: [
    AddonCell,
    MeteoAddon]
})

export class AddonModule {}
```

Note: **savedAddons** is an array containing string instance name.

So the main problem is how to get all the instanciated object AddonCell in order to access properties ?

Comment: not clear! Servicepage.ts refers to a component or injectable service?

Comment: It's a component

Comment: I edited my question to be more explicit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your helps guys but I found the solution !

I added on my **ServicePage.ts** this :

```
@ViewChildren('addoncell') components:QueryList<AddonCell>;
/// [...]
refreshInstalledAddons() : void {
    this.components.forEach(function(element) {
         console.log(element.cmpRef.instance.myVar);
    });
}
```

On **ServicePage.html**, I added an identifier with the **#**

```
<addon-cell #addoncell [type]="addon" *ngFor="let addon of savedAddons"></addon-cell>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class ServicesPage {
  @ViewChild(AddonCell)
  addonCell: AddonCell;

  getVar() {
     // this.addonCell.myVar
  }
}
```

Comment: Thx for your reply but I have an error message : "Unexpected value 'undefined' exported by the module 'AddonModule'"

Comment: make sure of the exported components  `AddonCell` and `MeteoAddon`.

Answer (score 0):

1- use the template reference in the parent component html

`<app-child-component #exampleReference></app-child-component>`

2- import @ViewChild in parent component class .ts

`import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core';`

3- import the child component class in the parent class .ts

`import { ChildComponent } from '../child/child.component';`

4- use @ViewChild() in the parent component class .ts

`@ViewChild('exampleReference', {static: false}) local_property_name: ChildComponent;`

now, you can access the child component's properties in the parent component using the `local_property_name` you chose.

ex. : `this.local_property_name.getFilterData();`